# VS 2005 Symbol mapping does not work in case of #ifdef

Tags: visual-studio

I am using VS 2005 as my IDE. Most of my source code uses pre-processor #ifdef. All the macro definitions that control #ifdef are present in a header file. Visual studio shows the code under #ifdef grey'ed out. Although the header file where the macros are defined is included in the source file. This is annoying since visual studio also will not create symbol mapping for the code it does not see. So in order to look for definition of a symbol I need to manually go and check it. I had added the header file where the macro definitions are present to the project. Also my include directories contain location of this file. Can someone tell my why would VS not recognize the macro definitions?

E.g.

```
File source.c

#include "defines.h"

#ifdef MY_DEFINE
int my_global = 0;
 void foo(void)
 {
   printf("I am here");
 }
#endif

File defines.h

#define MY_DEFINE
```

VS will show all the code under #ifdef as grey. If I want to check definition of my_global from other file I can not.